# Receiving email on GAE: still 60s to complete processing?

Tags: google-app-engine

My application is doing some juggling of email attachments.  So far it's clocking in around 20s and everything works fine.  But if I send larger attachments and it passes 60s, is it going to break?

Answer (score 0):

The App Engine doc does not say if the mail reception servlet have a timeout of 60s or 10 minutes, so it's hard to say.

In any case, I would recommend you perform the following in the servlet that handles `/_ah/mail` :

1. Store the mail content in Cloud Storage or blob store
2. Start a task to process this mail

That way you will take advantage of the retry capabilities of task, and you'll have 10 minutes to process your mail.

If you believe your task may take more than 10 minutes, you can either break up in smaller tasks (chained or parallel depending on your use case) or use modules to go beyond the 10 minutes limit. Note that modules will not stay up forever and you should not expect to perform 4 hour tasks on modules, for example.